# Crystal Report folder path

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

This code doesnt find the path of the Crystal Report.
I still get File not found.
Whats the problem?

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        string reportPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string reportFullPath = Path.Combine(reportPath, "CrystalReport1.rpt");
        if (!File.Exists(reportFullPath))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
            return;
        }

        cryRpt.Load(reportFullPath);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

ReportPath = C:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\Area_Progetto\backup\Area_Progetto_10_04_2014\Area_Proget‌​to_27_02_2014\Area_Progetto_DATA_MAGAZINE\Data_Magazine\Data_Magazine\bin\Debug reportFullPath = C:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\Area_Progetto\backup\Area_Progetto_10_04_2014\Area_Proget‌​to_27_02_2014\Area_Progetto_DATA_MAGAZINE\Data_Magazine\Data_Magazine\bin\Debug\C‌​rystalReport1.rpt

Comment: Is C‌​rystalReport1.rpt in C:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\Area_Progetto\backup\Area_Progetto_10_04_2014\Area_Proget‌​to_27_02_2014\Area_Progetto_DATA_MAGAZINE\Data_Magazine\Data_Magazine\bin\Debug\? I suspect it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The report file is probably not being copied to your output directory; change its build properties so that it does:

1. Highlight the file in Solution Explorer
2. Open the Properties window
3. Change Build Action to "Content"
4. Change "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if Newer"

   [image: Build Action]